# How can I regenerate .thumbnails folder in DCIM

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, gallery, thumbnails

I accidentally deleted the contents of `.thumbnails` folder in DCIM in sdcard. After deleting it I am unable to access `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID` however `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` is having all the images. How do I regenerate thumbnails in the `.thumbnails` folder to get the details of `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID`?

I initially had the idea that the gallery app in Android generates thumbnails in the `.thumbnails` folder so what I did was clear the cache of gallery app. Unmounted the sdcard and mounted it again in the hope that `.thumbnail` folder will have all the thumbnails when I relaunch the app

I am using HTC One V(Android version 4.0)

Comment: You answered yourself. The gallery automatically recreates the thumbnails..

Answer (score 5):

Go to Setting-->Applications--->Gallery-->Clear Cache

After clearing the cache, open the gallery app, it will automatically regenerate thumbnails.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for something else & came across this... 
The pathway to an apps cache has changed slightly since original posting back in 2012.

In Marshmallow (at least): 
Settings→Apps→Gallery→Storage→Clear Cache