# Images not displaying in Galary folder

Tags: images

In samsung galaxy ace s5830i the photos in sd card are not displaying in galary folder why? That is some image folder are not displaying but it is there in myfiles folder. Even songs are getting removed automatically from playlist why it happening like please someone help on this.... Recently im facing this problem. Plsss help.....

Comment: possible duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25676/how-do-i-make-older-images-in-my-sdcard-dcim-folder-show-up-in-gallery

Comment: See http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/68802/images-are-not-being-scanned-in-kitkat  and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32925/how-can-i-regenerate-thumbnails-folder-in-dcim as well.

Comment: As per question number 68802 i try to download fx apps but im getting erorrcode 927

Comment: Please do mention that the error you're getting is in Play Store. It is not obvious always because you can download an app from a browser too. Anyway, for the error, see this http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/103564/error-927-while-updating-youtube/103570#103570

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i need answer for the first one please help what will be problem

Answer (score 0):

Check if the folders you store your photos in have a file called .nomedia in it. It is used to flag folders for media players (gallery, music, etc.) not to scan